# How to get better address results with Google Places API?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-maps-api-2

I want the user to have autofill of address in his form through Google Places API. The API has been implemented, but I dont see the addresses as seen in Google Maps. We are not showing any map to the user in the form.

1. What is the difference in output between Google Places and Maps?
2. Is there a way to include results from Maps too?

Comment: If you are talking about autofill, I guess you need to look into the Google Autocomplete API.

Comment: Please note that [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps) for public consumption is a different product from the [Maps Platform APIs](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/). Results are not guaranteed to always be exactly the same for the two products.

You can start off with this guide for more info on the Places API Autocomplete:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

If you're having problems with exact addresses, please do provide exact samples, your expected result and what you get instead so we can give more relevant information.